# Regex vs. Piping in terms of speed

Tags: c, regex, piping

I'm writing a simple ncurses GUI wrapper for [nmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap) under Linux, to make it simpler to read and understand the ouput. However, when it comes to parsing the output is it faster to use POSIX regex and evaluate every expression in my code, or pipe the nmap output to utilities such as `grep`, `sed` or `cut`?

For example, if I want to retrieve online hosts in a subnet, which of the following solutions could be better?

```
pipe = popen("nmap -sn xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24", "r");
if (pipe == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error creating the pipe: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit (1);
}

while (!feof (pipe)) {
    if (fgets (buff, BUFF_SIZE, pipe) != NULL)  {

        /* perform regex evaluations here */

        printf ("%s", buff);
    }
}

pclose (pipe);
```

**vs.**

```
pipe = popen("nmap -sn xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/24 | grep -E 'pattern' | ...", "r");
if (pipe == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error creating the pipe: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit (1);
}

while (!feof (pipe)) {
    if (fgets (buff, BUFF_SIZE, pipe) != NULL)  {
        printf ("%s", buff);
    }
}

pclose (pipe);
```

Comment: I would run some benchmarking tests if I were you.

Comment: I would benchmark it, but I would think that using regex would be faster because it's what those tools are probably going to do anyway, plus you have the overhead of telling the OS to start another process and all that that implies

Comment: @Eregrith well, the main reason why I asked this is because I've never used the POSIX regex library before, so I'd avoid learning something new if it is worthless and there are faster methods.

Comment: Learning about regex is NEVER worthless :D !

Comment: @SethCarnegie yes, but maybe those tools performs some kind of optimization that I'm not even aware of.

Comment: It's unlikely that any optimisation they could perform would outweigh the cost of starting up another process

Comment: The real question here is: does it matter? Unless there's some need for seriously high-performance work here, which I'm not seeing, it's likely a pointless optimization.

Comment: As tbert said.  It doesn't look like the user would notice any timing differences no matter which technique you used.

Comment: The bottleneck here is going to be the network operations performed by nmap, not parsing its output.

Answer (score 0):

Do your benchmark. I recomend to use http://goo.gl/E3jbM for testing. Please let me know if you need help on the benchmark.